# отправка смс через php

Tags: php, sms

Как отправить СМС-сообщение на телефон, используя стандартную функцию `mail()` в PHP?

Comment: выбираешь любой сервис отправки смс(по приемлимой цене/тарифу) ну и дальше к их api. У многоих уже есть готовые функции для отправки.

Comment: береш усб модем https://xida.ru/node/407

Comment: У некоторых операторов была раньше услуга типа "Email2sms", даже бесплатно.